# MVC events do not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events

There is a task to subscribe to events generated by a third-party library. The library is connected in References.

In the desktop application everything works fine:

```
public class TEvents3 : TEvents
{

    public static TEvents3 Instance
    {
        get { return new TEvents3(); }
    }

}    

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var t = TEvents3.Instance;
}
```

All the same thing I do in the WEB (asp.net MVC). Events do not work.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   var t = TEvents3.Instance;
}
```

There are suspicions that the events in the WEB have some kind of specificity. Knowing people tell me what I'm doing wrong and why the events do not work?

Comment: What 3rd  party library? What are you trying to do? Web is a stateless application encompassing multiple sessions and doesn't use .Net Events the same way

Comment: A third-party library is a DLL library (written in С#) that looks at database changes and, if changes are detected, generates an event.

In the desktop application, I can subscribe to the events of this library, in a web application, I also subscribe to events, but the web does not respond to them.

I think there are differences in the workings of events on desktop applications and web applications, but neither did I find documentation on events on the web.

Comment: I know what a third party library is; I was asking what is the name of it. Dealing with ASP.NET and IIS throw all sorts of challenges at traditional events; IIS may turn the application off if there are no visitors for a period of time. Even if there are visitors, how will an event firing actually be propagated to the client?